# Trying to understand how Tasks works with blocking calls

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I recently started studying the `asyncio` library with the goal of replacing a big thread based application with async.

Reading the `asyncio` [documentantion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#id1) I stumbled upon an example where 
the `create_task` is being used. Because I'm stuck for now with python 3.6, I changed the `create_task` call with
the [`ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future), yielding the current code:

```py
# Python 3.6
import asyncio
import time


async def say_after(delay, what):
    print(f"start {what}")  # Added for better vizualization of what is happening
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(
        say_after(1, 'hello'))

    task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(
        say_after(2, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    # Wait until both tasks are completed (should take
    # around 2 seconds.)
    await task1
    await task2

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

And with the output:

```
started at 15:23:11
start hello
start world
hello
world
finished at 15:23:13
```

From what I can understand, the event loop:

- First starts the task `task1`;
- After hitting the `asyncio.sleep` it changes the context to the second `task2`; and
- When the first sleep is over, it changes to `task1` and equally the same thing occurs with the `task2` when its sleep call is over.

With all of that said, one of the requirements of my application is that we have some blocking calls that would needed to be converted to a coroutine. 
I created this mock code for testing the [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=run_in_executor#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) function with this goal:

```py
# Python 3.6
import asyncio
import time

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def normal_operations():
    print("start blocking")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("ended blocking")


async def async_operation():
    print("start non blocking")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("ended non blocking")


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(
            loop.run_in_executor(pool, normal_operations)
        )

    task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(
        async_operation()
    )

    await task1
    await task2

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

I expected that the output would be similar to the first example, but when I ran this code the output was:

```
started at 15:28:06
start blocking
ended blocking
start non blocking
ended non blocking
finished at 15:28:09
```

The two functions ran in order, not like the first example where the start `print` calls were called one before the other.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, my guess is that the `run_in_executor` function does not truly create an async call, or maybe I just implemented it wrong, I don't know.

Comment: In Python 3.6 you can use the `create_task` method on the event loop (which you can obtain with a call to `get_event_loop()`), having the same semantics as the top-level method added in 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think got the error.

I was awaiting the non-blocking operation outside the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and in the `__exit__` dunder a `shutdown` function is being called with the `wait=True` parameter, so basically the executor was blocking my code.

Fixed code:

```
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()

    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(loop.run_in_executor(pool, normal_operations))
    task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(async_operation())

    await task1
    await task2

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    pool.shutdown(wait=True)
```

With the expected output:

```
started at 16:20:48
start non blocking
start blocking
ended blocking
ended non blocking
finished at 16:20:50
```

Comment: That's correct. An even simpler option is to pass `None` as the first argument to `run_in_executor`, which will use the default executor of the event loop, [guaranteed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=set_default_executor#asyncio.loop.set_default_executor) to be a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.